# What is the exact size of MySQL?

Tags: mysql

My friend will run a website with 200 GB disk space, and he is asking about the size of MySQL the free edition, is it limited only to the size of the disk space?

Comment: This question belongs to serverfault. Besides that, is 200GB the available space, or the space the website is using? Websites won't usually reach the 200GB size for a database, and the space MySQL binaries are using depends on platform.

Comment: Do you mean the size of the mysql library/software, or the size of the database it can create?

Comment: Just a note that this has nothing to do with which edition of MySQL is being used.

Answer (score 3):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-table.html

For tables :

```
Win32 w/ FAT/FAT32        2GB/4GB
Win32 w/ NTFS              2TB (possibly larger)
Linux 2.2-Intel 32-bit    2GB (LFS: 4GB)
Linux 2.4+                (using ext3 file system) 4TB
Solaris 9/10                16TB
MacOS X w/ HFS+          2TB
NetWare w/NSS file system   8TB
```

> The effective maximum table size for MySQL databases is usually determined by operating system constraints on file sizes, not by MySQL internal limits.

I think this sums it up :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on table size (not database size) that is platform-dependent - see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-table.html).